# DataSet XML Response from Web Service consumption

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, dataset

Below is the valid and updated XML I was trying to consume:

```
<DataSet xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
    <xs:schema xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" id="NewDataSet">
    <xs:element name="response">
    <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="user" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <xs:complexType>
    <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="status" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <xs:complexType>
    <xs:attribute name="code" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="value" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="description" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="error" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <xs:complexType>
    <xs:attribute name="code" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="message" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="operation" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="timestamp" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
    <xs:complexType>
    <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <xs:element ref="response"/>
    </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    </xs:schema>
    <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
    <NewDataSet xmlns="">
    <response diffgr:id="response1" msdata:rowOrder="0" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted" operation="AUTHENTICATION" timestamp="2015-11-19 18:21:17.457" msdata:hiddenresponse_Id="0">
    <user diffgr:id="user1" msdata:rowOrder="0" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted" id="blumaesnetwork" msdata:hiddenresponse_Id="0"/>
    <status diffgr:id="status1" msdata:rowOrder="0" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted" code="315" value="FAILED" description="Authentication Failed. User ID Not Found" msdata:hiddenresponse_Id="0"/>
    <error diffgr:id="error1" msdata:rowOrder="0" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted" code="-1" message="User Not Found" msdata:hiddenresponse_Id="0"/>
    </response>
    </NewDataSet>
    </diffgr:diffgram>
    </DataSet>
```

With the C# code below:

```
x.LoadXml(_xmlString);

XDocument x1 = new XDocument();
x1 = XDocument.Parse(_xmlString);

IEnumerable<responseStatus> ListRsts = (from e in x1.Descendants("responseStatus")
                                        select new responseStatus
                                        {
                                           code = e.Element("code").Value,
                                           value = e.Element("value").Value,
                                           description = e.Element("description").Value
                                        });
foreach (var br in ListRsts)
         codeField = (br.code);
```

It keeps throwing error that i missed "diffgr".

Comment: "that i missed 'diffgr'" doesn't sound like any error I've ever seen from .NET.  What is the *actual* error?

Comment: Your XML doesn't contain namespace for `diffgr` & `msdata`. You should have a root node with these namespaces in your XML.

Comment: The Actuall Error: An exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in System.Xml.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: 'diffgr' is an undeclared prefix. Line 1, position 49.

Comment: @RahulSingh can you kindly help me with how i can do that please..maybe modify my code?

Comment: @TundeFatukasi - That depends on how that XML is getting generated cz that itself is wrong.

Comment: As @RahulSingh says, your XML is invalid.  Try uploading it to http://codebeautify.org/xmlvalidate and you see many errors about missing definitions for namespace prefixes.  This needs to be fixed on the server side.  Are you sure you didn't omit any portion of the XML from your question?

Comment: Yes you very correct @dbc the XML has lots of errors. Thanks guys really appreciate

Comment: i got the completed and valid xml:

Answer (score 0):

What you get as a respsone XML is a saved [DataSet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Data.DataSet(v=vs.110).aspx). Instead of trying to decipher the [diffgram](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172088(v=vs.110).aspx) it generates you better leverage the [ReadXml](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.readxml(v=vs.110).aspx) method of that type. It is fully equipped to read the xml and gives you specified behavior on the Tables and [Relationships](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.childrelations(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
var ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml(File.Open(@"C:\temp\ds.xml", FileMode.Open));

var listOfStatus = from row in ds.Tables["response"].Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
       from status in row.GetChildRows("response_status")
       select new { code = status["code"], 
                    value = status["value"], 
                    description = status["description"] };

foreach(var stat in listOfStatus)
{
    // do what ever you need to do with the Status record(s)
}
```

In the above code I read the rows in the table response and then fetch the childrows for the table status. For every status row an anonymous type is created with the three fields you seem to be interested in. You can process those by iterating over the IEnumerable of that anonymous type.